# Showing $\Im\int_{C}\left(\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{1-s}\right)ds=\pi$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

While I'm working on zeta function (nontrivial zeros), I stuck at a Integral calculation. I want to prove:
$$
\Im\int_{C}\left(\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{1-s}\right)ds=\pi
$$
Here, C is the inverse L-shaped integral path through $(2+0T\rightarrow 2+iT\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}+iT)$.

I don't know how to calculate the integral.

Comment: I know very little about complex analysis (I am an undergrad math student and my complex analysis course starts in a few days) so I'm afraid I can't help you, but you will attract more help if you show some of the motivation for this problem and your thoughts/attempts/struggles with it so far.

Comment: Are you sure that the result is independant from parameter $T$ ?

Comment: yes. I used that $\arctan(T) + \arctan(\frac{1}{T}) = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: If $\ln$ and $\arg$ are the principal values, then
$$\operatorname {Im} \int_{[2, 2 + i T, 1/2 + i T]}
 \left( \frac 1 s + \frac 1 {s - 1} \right) ds =
\operatorname {Im} (\ln s + \ln(s - 1)) \bigg\rvert_{s = 2}^{1/2 + i T} = \\
\arg \left( \frac 1 2 + i T \right) +
 \arg \left( -\frac 1 2 + i T \right).$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We assume of course $T \ne 0$ (if $T=0$, path(C) would pass through pole $1$, which is evidently forbidden).

You just have to parametrize the two line segments, resp. by

$s=2+it \ \ (0 \le t \le T) \ \ \ \ $ and $ \ \ \ s=t+iT \ \ (1/2 \le t \le 2) \ $ resp.

In this way your integral is the sum of $I_1$ and $I_2$ where:

$$I_1:=\int_{t=0}^T\left(\frac{1}{2+it}-\frac{1}{1-(2+it)}\right)dt$$

$$I_2=\int_{t=2}^{1/2}\left(\frac{1}{t+iT}-\frac{1}{1-(t+iT)}\right)dt$$

that are not difficult to integrate.

Advice: think to multiply by the complex conjugate of each denominator. For example, the first integral of $I_1$ can be written:

$$\int_{t=0}^T\frac{1}{2+it}dt=\int_{t=0}^T\frac{2-it}{4+t^2}dt=\left[\arctan(t/2)-i\frac12\log(4+t^2) \right]_0^T$$

**Important remark:** The intermediate point $2+iT$ **can be dropped**. Indeed, integrating along the single segment path $C'$: $[2+0i,1/2+Ti]$ will yield the same result! The reason is that the first path $C$ can be "distorted" into $C'$ without crossing any of the two poles $0,1$ of the function to be integrated.

I have checked numerically the result (more exactly imaginary part $=\pi$, whatever $T>0$, **but** $-\pi$ is $T<0$) using the Matlab function "integral" with "Waypoints" (intermediate points) enabling to compute the integral of a complex function along a broken line. Here is the script I have written for that:

> ```
> a=2+0.*i;
> for T=0.1:0.1:5
>    b=2+T*i;c=0.5+T*i;
>    I=integral(@(z)(1./z-1./(1-z)),a,c,'Waypoints',b);
>    imag(I)
> end;
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to understand.

Comment: I'm still not familiar with complex integrals, but I found this result interesting. I try to study more complex analysis. Thank you for your answer.